# jQuery- Not able to select the right td

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I can't seem to identify what went wrong with my jquery such that it keeps sending null data. Basically, after clicking a button I get a bunch of results and I want to be able to press edit and then edit that row which I can do but the values don't go into my ajax post to my api. I think that it would be my variable not selecting the correct `td` thus resulting in nothing being sent to the ajax post.

**HTML:**

```
<table id="results" class="hidden" cellspacing=10px>
        <thead>
            <tr class = "spacing">
                <th id= "samIdTable">SAM ID</th>
                <th id= "itemDescrip">Item Description</th>
                <th id= "issuedQty">Issued QTY</th>
                <th id= "openingQty">Opening QTY</th>
                <th id= "closingQty">Closing QTY</th>
                <th id= "corruptedQty">Corrupted QTY</th>
                <th id="Remarks">Remarks</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="bResults">
        <tr class="rowdata">
         <td>hi</td>
         <td>hi</td>
         <td>hi</td>
         <td>hi</td>
         <td>hi</td>
         <td>hi</td>
         <td>hi</td>
         <td><input class="button-edit" type="submit" id="edit" value="Edit" onclick="edit(this)"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="rowdata">
         <td>hi</td>
         <td>hi</td>
         <td>hi</td>
         <td>hi</td>
         <td>hi</td>
         <td>hi</td>
         <td>hi</td>
         <td><input class="button-edit" type="submit" id="edit" value="Edit" onclick="edit(this)"></td>
         </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

**JS CODE**

```
function edit(el){

var currentTD =  $(el).closest('tr').find('td'); // tds except the td which closest to the edit button
var samId = currentTD.find("td:nth-child(1)").val();
var itemDescrip= currentTD.find("td:nth-child(2)").val();
var issueQty = currentTD.find("td:nth-child(3)").val();
var openingQty =currentTD.find("td:nth-child(4)").val();
var closingQty = currentTD.find("td:nth-child(5)").val();
var corruptedQty = currentTD.find("td:nth-child(6)").val();
var Remarks = currentTD.find("td:nth-child(7)").val();  
var postData = { "samId": samId,  "itemDescrip": itemDescrip, "issueQty" : issueQty,
                "openQty" : openingQty, "closeQty" :closingQty, 
                "corrupQty": corruptedQty, "remarks": Remarks};
var postJSON = JSON.stringify(postData);
if ($(el).val() == 'Edit') {                  
    $.each(currentTD, function () {
         $(this).prop('contenteditable', true);

    });  
} else {
    $.each(currentTD, function () {
        $(this).prop('contenteditable', false);
    });
}
$(el).val($(el).val() == 'Edit' ? 'Save' : 'Edit');
if($(el).val() == 'Edit' ){
   $.ajax({
    url: "http://localhost:3000/api/updateRecord", // server url
    type: "POST", //POST or GET
    contentType: "application/json", // data to send in ajax format or querystring format
    data: postJSON,
    dataType : "JSON", //dataType is you telling jQuery what kind of response to expect
    success: function(response) {
        alert('success');
         if(response){
            var txt = "";
            txt += "<tr class='rowdata'><td>"+response.samID+"</td>"
                   +"<td>"+response.itemDescription+"</td>"
                   +"<td>"+response.issuedQTY + "</td>"
                   +"<td>"+response.openingQTY + "</td>"
                   +"<td>"+response.closingQTY+"</td>"
                   +"<td>"+response.corruptedQTY+"</td>"
                   +"<td>"+response.Remarks+"</td>"
                   +"</td>"+"</tr>";
         }
          if(txt != ""){
                $("#results").removeClass("hidden");
                $("#bResults").append(txt);
            }
    },
    error: function(response) {
        alert('error');
    }
});
}
}
```

Do tell me if additional information is needed. Thank you in advance. Don't understand what is with the downvotes but I did state if additional information is needed, I will provide. If not, at least state reasons as to why it is downvoted and I could improve on it next time.

Comment: The issue is with `currentTD.find("td:nth-child(1)").val();` syntax. you are dealing with **td** and it does not have value property in it.. you need to extract its content using the `.text()` .. so your code should be `currentTD.find("td:nth-child(1)").text();` and similar to all other lines of code..

Comment: @RajshekarReddy Does that mean I still need to `JSON.stringify()`?

Comment: that depends on how you are receiving your data on the server side.  if the server code is expecting a string then yes JSON.stringify is required. Else if it expects a object then not required. Even if you stringify the current code will throw error in the line  `data: postJSON,` .. you need to either assign this value to a object property or pass it in query string.. I would say not stringifying is best choice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code `var currentTD =  $(el).closest('tr').find('td');` you have already selected the nearest `<td>` with query which does not have child `<td>` .Also you cannot get the value of td using `.val()`.Use `.html()` instead. 
I have modified some of your code like below.

Your html

```
<table id="results" class="hidden" cellspacing=10px>
        <thead>
            <tr class = "spacing">
                <th id= "samIdTable">SAM ID</th>
                <th id= "itemDescrip">Item Description</th>
                <th id= "issuedQty">Issued QTY</th>
                <th id= "openingQty">Opening QTY</th>
                <th id= "closingQty">Closing QTY</th>
                <th id= "corruptedQty">Corrupted QTY</th>
                <th id="Remarks">Remarks</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="bResults">
        <tr class="rowdata">
         <td>1</td>
         <td>2</td>
         <td>3</td>
         <td>4</td>
         <td>5</td>
         <td>6</td>
         <td>7</td>
         <td><input class="button-edit" type="submit" id="edit" value="Edit" onclick="edit(this)"></td>
        <tr class="rowdata">
         <td>8</td>
         <td>9</td>
         <td>10</td>
         <td>11</td>
         <td>12</td>
         <td>13</td>
         <td>14</td>
         <td><input class="button-edit" type="submit" id="edit" value="Edit" onclick="edit(this)"></td>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

And your javascript

```
function edit(el){

var currentTD =  $(el).closest('tr').find('td'); // tds except the td which closest to the edit button

var current_id = $(el).closest('tr');

var samId = current_id.find("td:nth-child(1)").html();
var itemDescrip= current_id.find("td:nth-child(2)").html();
var issueQty = current_id.find("td:nth-child(3)").html();
var openingQty =current_id.find("td:nth-child(4)").html();
var closingQty = current_id.find("td:nth-child(5)").html();
var corruptedQty = current_id.find("td:nth-child(6)").html();
var Remarks = current_id.find("td:nth-child(7)").html();  
var postData = { "samId": samId,  "itemDescrip": itemDescrip, "issueQty" : issueQty,
                "openQty" : openingQty, "closeQty" :closingQty, 
                "corrupQty": corruptedQty, "remarks": Remarks};
var postJSON = JSON.stringify(postData);
if ($(el).val() == 'Edit') {                  
    $.each(currentTD, function () {
         $(this).prop('contenteditable', true);

    });  
} else {
    $.each(currentTD, function () {
        $(this).prop('contenteditable', false);
    });
}
$(el).val($(el).val() == 'Edit' ? 'Save' : 'Edit');
if($(el).val() == 'Edit' ){
   $.ajax({
    url: "http://localhost:3000/api/updateRecord", // server url
    type: "POST", //POST or GET
    contentType: "application/json", // data to send in ajax format or querystring format
    data: postJSON,
    dataType : "JSON", //dataType is you telling jQuery what kind of response to expect
    success: function(response) {
        alert('success');
         if(response){
            var txt = "";
            txt += "<tr class='rowdata'><td>"+response.samID+"</td>"
                   +"<td>"+response.itemDescription+"</td>"
                   +"<td>"+response.issuedQTY + "</td>"
                   +"<td>"+response.openingQTY + "</td>"
                   +"<td>"+response.closingQTY+"</td>"
                   +"<td>"+response.corruptedQTY+"</td>"
                   +"<td>"+response.Remarks+"</td>"
                   +"</td>"+"</tr>";
         }
          if(txt != ""){
                $("#results").removeClass("hidden");
                $("#bResults").append(txt);
            }
    },
    error: function(response) {
        alert('error');
    }
});
}
}
```

Hope it will work.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Both you and Shiladitya answer work nicely!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using find after getting the currentTD, I have used it as an array.

Please check the jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/jkpjjmeu/

```
function edit(el) {
    var currentTD =  $(el).closest('tr').find('td'); 
    var samId = currentTD[0].textContent;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. You and M. Deepak gave answers that both helped it to work. Would love to accept both but could only accept one.

Answer (score 0):

You're `<tr>`s don't close!

Add `</tr>` in the right places and try again.

Comment: Made a mistake in my posting of the question it had tr already